# Building a backend for mobile and web

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, architecture, smartphone

i want to build an application that will be accessible from web browsers, and will also be accessible from smartphones.

What is the best way of doing it, those are the 2 option i've thinking about:

1. Building a rails server that will serve the browsers, and will also be a rest api for the mobile app.
2. Build a separate rest API server that will be accessible from the mobile app and will also be accessible from the rails web server.

What do you think ? it should be pretty standard i believe.
Do you have any more idea for building it ?

Comment: Option 2 is better, Build one API which will serve both platforms. But If you are thinking of building native mobile application with User authentication/login functionality then this might be painful but not impossible. if Not then it should be straight forward to Use API's from one server for both platforms

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Keep it with 1 app server (running Rails)

--

**API**

Rails has a very strong structure, which you can use to create a [RESTful API](http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning) quite simply:

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :api do
   resources :posts #-> domain.com/api/posts
end

#app/controllers/api/posts_controller.rb
Class API::PostsController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :json
   # ... your methods here
end
```

This will allow you to send the requests you need

--

[**MIME Types**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type)

The second part of this is about [`mime types`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type), as stated by `snarf`. Rails, through the [`ActionDispatch::Http::MimeNegotiation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/MimeNegotiation.html) middleware, allows you to handle different *types* of request, providing you the ability to handle an `api` in the most efficient way

This means you can only allow `json` requests to your `api` controller - meaning that when you develop your mobile app, you can send the `api` requests to your Rails server, rather than a separate `API` one.

--

**Recommendation**

I would highly recommend using a single server, running rails

There are several reason for this:

> 1. Creating an API in Rails is actually quite simple
> 2. Using one server allows you to handle all the data in one place
> 3. Keeping a single server also ensures user authenticity across all platforms

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished easily with one server.

See: [`ActionController::MimeResponds`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html)

In your controller:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @people = Person.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @people }
    end
  end
  ...
```

This way you can *respond* with the *data format* (in this case **html** or **json**) dependent on the request type your controller receives.

`http://mydomain.com/people.json` 
or 
`http://mydomain.com/people.html`